# MarkLogic External Name

Tags: marklogic

[image: External Name]

The result number external name always returns zero. I don't know do I missing any code.

```
let $externalcnt := fn:count(xdmp:user-external-security(fn:data(fn:doc($user)/sec:user/sec:user-id)))
     return fn:concat('Num External Names: "', $externalcnt,'"'),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `xdmp:user-external-security()` function uses the external user id to lookup the user.

You are listing all of the `sec:user-id` values, but should instead obtain the user-id for all of the `/sec:user/sec:external-names/sec:external-name` and then use that ID to obtain the external-security:

```
doc()/sec:user/sec:external-names/sec:external-name ! xdmp:user(.) ! xdmp:user-external-security(.)
```